# How do I move a module group into a folder?

Tags: automated-testing, ranorex

I have created a group of modules in Ranorex Studio and it's now in the root folder of the project.

Because it's related to some user code modules that are in a subfolder, I want to move the module group to that subfolder as well.

Unfortunately, Ranorex Studio does not let me move it:

[image: Move Module Group]

How can I move the module group into a subfolder?

Answer (score 1):

Short: there's no solution.

The `.rxtmg` file is not a single module group, it's a module group**s** file. The association of modules into module groups is done in that file. Unfortunately, that's a 2 level hierarchy only and is not a real tree.

There cannot be more than one such file per project, so there's typically no need to move it into a subdirectory.